# RISCV toolchain disassembly omitting addresses

Tags: assembly, riscv, toolchain, objdump

I am using the RISCV toolchain to generate assembly code from .c files.

During the disassembly process:

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump -D -S -l -F -Mnumeric,no-aliases
```

noticed that some addresses are omitted, as shown below in the picture with  " ... "

[image]

Because the instructions are not aligned, it later creates a problem when trying to parse them in txt file. How this could be solved to avoid the misalignment?

Comment: Those are probably zeroes. Use `-z` or `--disassemble-zeroes`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks for your remarks. Indeed some were zeroes and some others just out of bounds.